# How to execute the "AL:GO!" task as part of a script

Tags: project, microsoft-dynamics, navision

Recently, my company started to focus **Extension_v2** development for Dynamics NAV BC. We store our code in an internal Git-Server. So far, so good.

*But startig a new project is still a very fiddly task.* You have to create a repository, clone it, execute the AL Code-Task, move the files to the fitting location push the repository to the correct upstream etc. And all this does not include the first initial Steps (README, CHANGELOG and all other fundamental files...).

So I wanted to write a small **PowerShell-Script**, to do all these initial steps before being able to start working on the Project.

The Problem: I could not find a way to **execute the "AL-GO!" task via script.**

I have already searched the Internet and some forums for an answer... but it seems like microsoft did not consider the possibility to execute tasks from the AL-Language-Extension via script.

I also played around with the New-NAVAppManifest and the New-NAVAppManifestFile command for the old Extension_V1 development, but that did not do the trick.

I am looking for a fair and easy way to combine the creation of the **app.json** file and the **launch.json** file with other commands to easily initialize a new Project without haveing to write all commands manually. Maybe I did not recognize the easy solution. Or maybe this is just the way we have to do it in Extension_v2.

Anyway, thanks for all your help nevertheless.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

**Stay away from Ext V1. It's highly deprecated at this point.**

First of all, why do you need to execute the **"AL-Go!"** via script? The "AL-Go!" command should already include all necessary steps to create an empty project including the **launch.json** and **app.json**. (minimal adjuments required dependent on your BC environment)

There is an **extension/plugin for Git in Visual Studio Code** which will handle all the repository stuff for you. You don't need to change file locations if everything is set up for Git. I rarely use it yet, but saw a demo for it on the Directions EMEA last year and I'm pretty sure it works at its current state (someone correct me if I'm wrong)

A way to implement the "AL-GO!" command for a script or for setting up additional steps in your project setup might be to write your own visual studio code extension/plugin which requires some additional know-how for that.

**OR**

You just change the settings/files of the default project, I bet there is at least a file for creating the initial AL project. Just change that to your requirements

Comment: We don´t use Ext. V1 anymore. I am sorry if you misunderstood that. We also use a **Gitblit** server which sits in our internal network. The problem is the fact, that creating a new repository requires a lot of moving files around (this is because of some security settings). Therefore the idea was to make the process of creating a new repository easier, by combining the creation of all needed files with the moving of the files to the target location.